# How to access individual character in Platform::String?

Tags: string, windows, visual-c++, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

How can I access an individual character in `Platform::String^`?

I am using this variable type because it appears to be the only way to write a string to a `TextBlock` on a Universal Windows App.

I have tried the following methods to get individual characters to no avail:

```
String ^ str = "string";
std::string::iterator it = str->begin(); //Error: platform string has no member "begin"
std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); //Error: expression must have a class type
str[0] = 't' /*Error: expression must have a pointer-to-object or handle-to-C++/CX 
mapping-array type*/
```

I am putting the String^ in a text block named "textBlock" as follows: `textBlock->Text = str;`

I am open to approaches other than modifying the `Platform::String`. My only requirement is that the string ends in a form that can be put into a TextBox

Comment: That doesn't look like any c++ I know.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf  It's certainly not c++11.  Please remove inappropriate tags.

Comment: I'm not terribly well versed in the technicalities of the language. Tags were fixed by Praetorian. Thanks.

Comment: `Platform::String^` is immutable. You have to create a new string.

Comment: I assumed I would have to do something like that. Could you elaborate on the process by which I might create a new string with the Platform:String's contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Platform::String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh755812.aspx) represents a sequential collection of Unicode characters that is used to represent text. The controlled sequence is immutable: Once constructed, the contents of a `Platform::String` can no longer be modified.

If you need a modifiable string, the canonical solution is to use another string class, and convert to/from `Platform::String` when calling the Windows Runtime, or receiving string data. This is explained under [Strings (C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh699879.aspx):

> The **Platform::String Class** provides methods for several common string operations, but it's not designed to be a full-featured string class. In your C++ module, use standard C++ string types such as [**wstring**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/wt3s3k55.aspx) for any significant text processing, and then convert the final result to [**Platform::String^**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh755812.aspx) before you pass it to or from a public interface.

You could rewrite your code sample as follows:

```
// Use a standard C++ string as long as you need to modify it
std::wstring s = L"string";
s[0] = L't';    // Replace first character

// Convert to Platform::String^ when required
Platform::String^ ps = ref new Platform::String(s.c_str(), s.length());
```

Comment: I put this in my program and it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the already supplied answer:  you are also able to change a Platform::String^ into a std::wstring so you can modify it, then you can always change it back to Platform::String^

```
Platform::String^ str = "string";
wstring orig (str->Data());
orig[0] = L't';
str = ref new Platform::String(orig.c_str());
```

Comment: When you say *"change"* you are hiding the fact, that you are reconstructing new objects, copying data back and forth. This is pretty much the same as my proposed solution, except, that you are using the wrong constructors, which will break as soon as the strings contain embedded NUL characters. Those are more common than you may think (e.g. the *lpstrFilter* field of the [OPENFILENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) structure).

Comment: @IInspectable His question used a Platform::String^, all I was trying to do was get him from where he was to a point where he could use your answer.  I wasn't trying to hide anything.  Also, this is the method used from msdn:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699879.aspx

Comment: I was commenting on your wording. You don't *"change"* a `Platform::String` into a `std::wstring`. You construct a new object, and after that, both exist. This is not converting one object into another, thereby consuming one of them. Besides, while you tried to provide information on how to get from a `Platform::String` to a `std::wstring` you lost the ability to preserve embedded NUL characters (as pointed out in my previous comment). This is also explained in the MSDN link we both linked to.

Comment: @IInspectable ohhhh,I see what you're getting at now.  I'm sorry, I misunderstood and/or misread.  You're correct on everything you pointed out.  Do you know how you would preserve those NUL chars?

Comment: By invoking constructors that take an explicit length argument (as illustrated in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37239662/1889329)).